# What does Worst case running time of Insertion Sort really means

Tags: insertion-sort

I don't know whether it is a right platform for asking this Question so don't be angry. My question is that we all know that Worst Case running time for Insertion Sort is O(n^2). Let's say that we have array of length 5 then how many number of Comparisons will be required to sort an array.

I am confused that for an array of length 5 will take 5^2 =25 number of comparisons. Am i right please correct me.

Comment: `n(n+1)/2` comparisons to be precise

Comment: Insertion sort browse the array in ascending order. The problem is that if your array is already sorted, but in descending order, the insertion sort will perform a lot of reverse browsing/value move  to put values in ascending order. And that's the worst case you talk about.